# InnoSetup: How to remove horizontal lines from wizard pages

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way to remove or hide the horizontal line controls from Innosetup wizard pages by code to give it a little more modern touch?

See example here:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The upper horizontal line highlighted in your screenshot is the `WizardForm.Bevel1` component, whilst the bottom one is the `WizardForm.Bevel` component. To hide both, you can write a script like this:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.Bevel.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.Bevel1.Visible := False;
end;
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Do you maybe have the control ID of the upper line available too?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed the top one. Fixed in the update.

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem solved.
Out of curiosity, how did you gather those control IDs?

Comment: You're welcome! Well, it was just a guess from the [`list of components`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardForm) available for the `WizardForm`. I usually use the design time form in Delphi, where I can click the component and it tells me the name of the control, but I don't have it by hand right now. The only thing I knew was it's a `TBevel` class type control.